# Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native

I am fixing a incompatibility issue related to AndroidX by adding 2 lines to `gradle.properties` under `android` for my RN 0.59 project.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Now there is another error with `run-android` related to `react-native-gesture-handler`. Then I `yarn remove` the current `react-native-gesture-handler` of `1.2.0` and add it back. The new version is `1.3.0`. Here is the error:

```
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:3: error: package android.support.v4.util does not exist
import android.support.v4.util.Pools;
                              ^
C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:19: error: package Pools does not exist
  private static final Pools.SynchronizedPool<RNGestureHandlerEvent> EVENTS_POOL =
                            ^
C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:3: error: package android.support.v4.util does not exist
import android.support.v4.util.Pools;
                              ^
C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:19: error: package Pools does not exist
  private static final Pools.SynchronizedPool<RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent> EVENTS_POOL =
                            ^
C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:20: error: package Pools does not exist
          new Pools.SynchronizedPool<>(TOUCH_EVENTS_POOL_SIZE);
                   ^
C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:20: error: package Pools does not exist
          new Pools.SynchronizedPool<>(TOUCH_EVENTS_POOL_SIZE);
                   ^
Note: C:\D\code\js\emps_app\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
6 errors

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The error is related 6 packages missing and I guess it is still related to Androidx. But I have no clue how to fix it. There is an issue post (for RN-gesture-handler) suggesting downgraded to version `1.0.5` for fixing but I wouldn't like to use such an old version.

Comment: Did you still face this error?

Answer (score 20):

It cause this error for the `RN 0.60`.
You can solve this by following,

```
npm i jetifier
npx jetify
```

fixed it for me on `RN 0.60`.

Have a good day.

Comment: this works but, you must be sure that `gradle.properties` contains this
`android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true`

Answer (score 5):

```
npm i jetifier
npx jetify
```

Fixed it for me on react-native 0.60

Be carefully for latest react-native version don't need

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

It is automatically linked by react-native 0.60

Answer (score 0):

As per my openion this error occurs due to incomplete installation and linking of npm library.
Follows these steps:-
At first Run this command inside your project (npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler).
Then link this library by running this command (react-native link react-native-gesture-handler).
Then run your project on devices or simulator , it will work.
If it doesn't work then manually install and link this library from link given below.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gesture-handler

Comment: Verified that `react-native-gesture-handler` had already been linked. The error is the same after link

Comment: Ohk .I can suggest you one more solution.You can try removing node modules from your project and then run this comand:-(npm install --save).And then after installing node modules run one more command (react-native link).i hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

> $ npm i react-native-gesture-handler
>
> $ react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
>
> Install Jetifier ->
>
> $ npm install --save-dev jetifier

or

> $ yarn add -D jetifier

Then ->  Edit your package.json and add a postinstall script: "postinstall": "npx jetify", like so:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "lockfileVersion": 1,
    "requires": true,
    "scripts": {
          "postinstall": "npx jetify"
    },
    ....
 }
```

> $ npm install or $ yarn
>
> $ npx jetify

[link](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/facebook/react-native/25483/508446776)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer for folks using RN < 0.60, as was the OP. I am using `react-native-gesture-handler` v 1.3.0 as this was the the last version before the library updated to AndroidX.

Although the OP ran into this by adding

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

to his project, I unwittingly added it by adding another library that had been converted to AndroidX, `react-native-safe-area-context`. I was expecting my build to fail when it got to that library, but I got really confused when it failed before that, while building `react-native-gesture-handler`. Apparently if `useAndroidX` and `enableJetifier` are set to true anywhere in the build it affects the whole build.

I fixed the problem by patching the new library to revert AndroidX. I got the patch [here](https://gist.github.com/brunolemos/ec886065b695d54ba25af7de47475c90#file-react-native-safe-area-context-0-3-5-patch).