# How to fix react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac Failed

Tags: android, react-native

I'm gettign this annoying error:

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   D:\FifaLeagueApp\FifaIL\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerModule.java:16: error: package com.facebook.react.module.annotations does not exist

I've tried many things but none helped...

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

build.gradle dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-exit-app')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-restart')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0' // v4
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.2.0' //v13
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

Don't know what to try anymore... any ideas?

Comment: You can follow the following answer to fix it.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/56930244/10456375]

Answer (score 4):

2 possible solutions:

1) mismatch version of RN and GestureHandler put an exact version of you react-native for example:

```js
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.57.5"
```

2) Your version of RN is too low and you need to downgrade your gesture handler by

```js
npm i react-native-gesture-handler@1.0.16 -D -E
```

or update version of RN but it may break other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

> It causes this error for the RN 0.60.
>   You can solve this by following

```
sudo npm i jetifier 
sudo npx jetify
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open gradle.properties and add following code:

```
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false
```